# How to import the content of a variable from a text file into bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like my bash script to import variables from a text file

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3
do
    IMPORT THE CONTENT OF FILE file$1.txt
    python $VAR
done
```

Where the file text contain the value of the variable as

```
VAR=SOMETHING
```

I tried `cat file$i.txt` but the `$VAR` is not populated.  What would be a way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `source`

```
$ cat vars.txt
var1="Hello"
var2="World"
$ source vars.txt
$ echo "$var1 $var2"
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

The backticks is the key here:

```
VAR=`cat file.txt`
```

Comment: Thanks @White Owl. Could you please explain why it puts the content "SOMETHING" into var and not the content "VAR=SOMETHING" into VAR?

Comment: Follow up question: would this still work if I had some VAR1 and VAR2 in the script and appropriately defined in the text file?